# apache skywalking 7.0.0 could not get service name in kubernetes cluster

Tags: microservices

I am using apache skywalking(7.0.0) in Kubernetes(v1.16.0) cluster to be my APM tool,but now I could not get service name in dashboard. This is my collector config in Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

MAINTAINER jiangxiaoqiang (jiangtingqiang@gmail.com)

ADD dolphin-service/build/libs/dolphin-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /root/dolphin-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD script/start-docker.sh /root/start-docker.sh

EXPOSE 11005
# ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/root/start-docker.sh"]

ENTRYPOINT exec java -Xmx256M -Xms128M -Dapp.id=0010020001 -javaagent:/opt/skywalking/agent/skywalking-agent.jar -Dskywalking.agent.service_name=0010020001 -Dskywalking.collector.backend_service=10.254.35.220:11800 -jar /root/dolphin-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

and this is my dashboard UI:

[image]

Is something I am missing? all data collected(Endpoint\Cache\Database\MQ) except the service.What should I do to make service data collect? When I see the log output:

```
2020-06-15 04:46:12,237 - graphql.execution.SimpleDataFetcherExceptionHandler -154193437 [qtp1107275448-39] WARN  [] - Exception while fetching data (/topo) : Service id is empty
org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.core.UnexpectedException: Service id is empty
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.storage.plugin.elasticsearch.query.TopologyQueryEsDAO.loadSpecifiedClientSideServiceRelations(TopologyQueryEsDAO.java:73) ~[storage-elasticsearch-plugin-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.core.query.TopologyQueryService.getServiceTopology(TopologyQueryService.java:106) ~[server-core-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.query.graphql.resolver.TopologyQuery.getServicesTopology(TopologyQuery.java:68) ~[query-graphql-plugin-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.query.graphql.resolver.TopologyQueryMethodAccess.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[reflectasm-1.11.7.jar:7.0.0]
    at com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.MethodFieldResolverDataFetcher.get(MethodFieldResolver.kt:147) ~[graphql-java-tools-5.2.3.jar:?]
    at graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy.fetchField(ExecutionStrategy.java:227) [graphql-java-8.0.jar:?]
    at graphql.execution.ExecutionStrategy.resolveField(ExecutionStrategy.java:170) [graphql-java-8.0.jar:?]
    at graphql.execution.AsyncExecutionStrategy.execute(AsyncExecutionStrategy.java:59) [graphql-java-8.0.jar:?]
    at graphql.execution.Execution.executeOperation(Execution.java:158) [graphql-java-8.0.jar:?]
    at graphql.execution.Execution.execute(Execution.java:100) [graphql-java-8.0.jar:?]
    at graphql.GraphQL.execute(GraphQL.java:558) [graphql-java-8.0.jar:?]
    at graphql.GraphQL.parseValidateAndExecute(GraphQL.java:500) [graphql-java-8.0.jar:?]
    at graphql.GraphQL.executeAsync(GraphQL.java:470) [graphql-java-8.0.jar:?]
    at graphql.GraphQL.execute(GraphQL.java:401) [graphql-java-8.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.query.graphql.GraphQLQueryHandler.execute(GraphQLQueryHandler.java:93) [query-graphql-plugin-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.query.graphql.GraphQLQueryHandler.doPost(GraphQLQueryHandler.java:83) [query-graphql-plugin-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.library.server.jetty.JettyJsonHandler.doPost(JettyJsonHandler.java:59) [library-server-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.library.server.jetty.JettyJsonHandler.service(JettyJsonHandler.java:107) [library-server-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.skywalking.oap.server.library.server.jetty.JettyJsonHandler.service(JettyJsonHandler.java:112) [library-server-7.0.0.jar:7.0.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841) [jetty-servlet-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:543) [jetty-servlet-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188) [jetty-server-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239) [jetty-server-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168) [jetty-server-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481) [jetty-servlet-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166) [jetty-server-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141) [jetty-server-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132) [jetty-server-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564) [jetty-server-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320) [jetty-server-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) [jetty-server-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279) [jetty-io-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110) [jetty-io-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124) [jetty-io-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672) [jetty-util-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590) [jetty-util-9.4.2.v20170220.jar:9.4.2.v20170220]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the dashboard default time filter value problem, the time range did not contains data:

```
curl 'https://skywalking.example.net/graphql' \
  -H 'authority: skywalking.example.net' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'dnt: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'origin: https://skywalking.example.net' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: empty' \
  -H 'referer: https://skywalking.example.net/' \
  -H 'accept-language: en,zh-CN;q=0.9,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,fr;q=0.6' \
  --data-binary $'{"query":"query queryServices($duration: Duration\u0021) {\\n    services: getAllServices(duration: $duration) {\\n      key: id\\n      label: name\\n    }\\n  }","variables":{"duration":{"start":"2020-06-03 1015","end":"2020-06-23 1030","step":"MINUTE"}}}' \
  --compressed
```

change the time start and end to having collection data area.